# How is "Orthogonal distance" computed?

Tags: pca, distance, chemometrics

I was reading the vignette of the R package `chemometrics` ([link](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/chemometrics/vignettes/chemometrics-vignette.pdf)). In the second paragraph (right below the first equation) of Page 12, the author writes:

> the OD (Orthogonal Distance) is calculated in the original space as the orthogonal distance of an object to the PCA subspace or, in other
>   words, the distance between the object and its orthogonal projection
>   on the PCA subspace.

Can someone elaborate upon how exactly the orthogonal distance is calculated (some R code as an illustrative example would be greatly appreciated, if possible!)

Comment: Did you try calculating the orthogonal projection?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Given a $n$ by $p$ matrix $\pmb X$ the SVD decomposition of $\pmb X$ is:

$$\text{svd}((\pmb X-\bar{x})/\sqrt{n-1})=\pmb{UDV}'$$

(I will denote $\pmb V_k$ the matrix formed of the first $k$ columns of $\pmb V$ and $\pmb D_k$ the diagonal matrix formed of the first $k$ rows and columns of $\pmb D$)

The SVD decomposition divides the total variance of $\pmb X$ unto two 
mutually orthogonal components:

- The variance of the projection of $(\pmb X-\bar{x})$ on the space spanned by the first $k$ singular vectors of $(\pmb X-\bar{x})$:

$$\sqrt{(\pmb X-\bar{x})'\pmb{V_kD_k^{-1}V_k'}(\pmb X-\bar{x})}$$

- The variance of the projection of $(\pmb X-\bar{x})$ on the space orthogonal to the first $k$ singular vectors of $(\pmb X-\bar{x})$:

$$\sqrt{(\pmb X-\bar{x})'(\pmb{I_k}-\pmb{V_kV_k'})(\pmb X-\bar{x})}$$

(where $\pmb I_k$ is the rank $k$ identity matrix) which is also equivalent to:

$$||\pmb X-\bar{x}-(\pmb X-\bar{x})\pmb{V_k^{}V_k'}||$$.

In R

```
n<-100
p<-20
k<-5
x<-matrix(rnorm(n*p),nc=p) #your data matrix

#the orthogonal distances:

data_centered<-sweep(x,2,colMeans(x),FUN="-")
loadings<-svd(data_centered/sqrt(nrow(data_centered)-1),nu=0)$v[,1:k]
orthDist<-data_centered-data_centered%*%loadings%*%t(loadings)
orthDist<-sqrt(rowSums(orthDist*orthDist))
```

you will find a more complete code to compute OD (and SD, the statistical distances on the space spanned by the loading matrix)
 in the `rrcov` package:

```
library(rrcov)
rrcov:::.distances
```

the function is not documented, but the slot `res@od` therein are the orthogonal 
distances.